# Google Search Appliance - Get Search Resuls in XML

Tags: xml, google-search-appliance

I've been trying to determine how to do this, and struggling finding examples.  I have a site that will need heavy custom skinning, and would like to run searches on the site, and execute a query where an API call could make the call to the GSA.

Is it as simple as doing an HTTP callout with a parameter (I tried with output=xml which didn't work)?  If anyone could point me in a direction to get started, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Plus, There will  be `&proxystylesheet=default_frontend` query string. Remove it and you will see the results in XML.

Just the 'q' is sufficient to bring results in XML. eg., `http://gsahost:port/search?q=engine` and later add the search request parameters that you need.

If you are using the default search interface of GSA that is accessible in port 80 then removing the proxystylesheet parameter will give you results in XML

Comment: Hi Aswath; thanks for the reply.  I'm not currently passing the proxystylesheet paramater through, do I need to explicitly clear it (i.e. is "default_frontend" used as a default if unset)?

Comment: Udpated the answer. Yes remove it.

Comment: @user3014439  You should have a look at the search protocol: https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/xml_reference.pdf